# Implementing a reoccurring subscription based logic in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, scheduled-tasks

I have two models. A plan model which comprises of three Plans, and a Subscription model. A user is permitted to have only one active plan at a time. The logic is that when a user first subscribes to a plan, by default, the `status` will be `pending`. After the site admin confirms the subscription(deposit), he will toggle the `active` Boolean field, and automatically, the status will change to `Confirmed`.

Now, where I have issues is with implementing what happens after the subscription has been confirmed. I will try explaining the logic as much as I can. A user is supposed to be receiving a daily profit till the plan expiries. Let me cite an example: Suppose **User A** subscribes to the `basic plan`. The `basic plan` has a daily percentage bonus of 10% and lasts for 7 days(`duration`). Now after the admin activates the subscription, the user is supposed to be receiving a daily profit of 10% of his investment for a duration of 7 days. Assuming he subscribes with $100.00, by the end of the first day, his balance should be $110.00, and so on. Then after the plan expiries, the status should automatically change to `Expired`, the `active` field will change to False, and the percentage should stop adding.

Here comes my question, how do implement this logic of incrementing the user's balance daily automatically till his current plan expiries, and how I automatically deactivate the subscription once its expiries. I tried using loops, but it was a terrible idea. I saw some articles about Celery, RQ, threading, Cron, and so on. But I don't know how to go about any of them. Can someone please help me out with the solution to the problem. I would appreciate if the person implements the logic using whatever tool of his/her choice and explain the idea behind that to me. Instead of pointing me from one article to the other. Thanks.
If you need more clarification, please let me know. I'm using PostgreSQL.

**Here is my Plan model**

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    SUB_PLAN = (
        ('Basic', 'Basic Plan'),
        ('Gold', 'Gold Plan'),
        ('Platinum', 'Platinum Plan')
    )
    plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SUB_PLAN)
    percent = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    referral_bonus = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)
    min = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    max = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2) 
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**Here is my Subscription model**

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    SUB_STATUS =(
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Confirmed', 'Confirmed'),
        ('Expired', 'Expired')
    ) 
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Deposit", editable=False)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="plan")
    sub_method = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=SUB_METHOD, default='Wallet')
    sub_currency = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=SUB_CURRENCY, default='Btc')
    sub_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    expires_at = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=SUB_STATUS, default="Pending")
    verified_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    initiated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**LOGIC THAT OCCURS WHEN THE ADMIN TOGGLES THE ACTIVE FIELD**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Subscription)
def activate_subcription(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.active == True:
        user=instance.user
        status = "Confirmed", verified_on = timezone.now()
        expires_at = date.today() + timedelta(days=instance.plan.duration)
        user.balance = F('balance') + instance.sub_amount
        user.save()
```